# Autoplay carrousel with html and css

Tags: html, css

"Hello guys, how are you doing?"

"I need to create a carousel with autoplay videos just like the one on the website https://flowstatebranding.com/. When entering the page, it is the first thing you see. How can I start it so that it is automatic?"
i just need do this with html and css nothing of js.

"Thank you."
this doesnt work in my html one page

```js
<script>
    $('button').click(function () {
        $("article").toggleClass("paused")
    });
</script>
```

```css
<style>
    button {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    section {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    article {
        display: flex;
        width: 200%;
        animation: bannermove 20s linear infinite;
    }

    article.paused {
        -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
        animation-play-state: paused;
    }

    div {
        width: 100%;
    }

    ul {
        display: flex;
        background: red;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    li {
        width: 100%;
        background: blue;
    }

    li:nth-child(2) {
        background: green;
    }

    li:nth-child(3) {
        background: yellow;
    }

    @keyframes "bannermove" {
        0% {
            transform: translateX(0);
        }

        100% {
            transform: translateX(-50%);
        }
    }
</style>
```

```html
<body>
    <section>
        <article>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/ffffff.png" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/ffffff.png" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/ffffff.png" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/ffffff.png" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/ffffff.png" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/ffffff.png" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/ffffff.png" /></li>
                    <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/ffffff.png" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Look up how to create a 'marquee' - that acts like a continuous slider (but don't use the HTML marquee tag which is deprecated). Have a go at coding it and if you still have a problem put your code into your question with a description of what isn't working [we aren't here to write code from scratch but to debug your code].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.